# If $Tv=\mu v$ for some $\mu>0$, then $v\in\ker(T^{1/2})^\perp$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Let

- $V$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $T$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $V$
- $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$ with $$Tv_n=\mu_nv_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$

> How can we prove that $$v_n\in\ker(T^{1/2})^\perp$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\mu_n>0$?

I'm not sure how I need to prove the statement. Obviously, if $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\mu_n>0$, then $$v_n\not\in\ker T\supseteq\ker(T^{1/2})\;,$$ but I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with
$$
               \overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}=\mathcal{N}(T)^\perp.
$$
As you noted, $\mathcal{N}(T^{1/2})\subseteq\mathcal{N}(T)$.
Because $T^{1/2}$ is selfadjoint,
$$
                 \|T^{1/2}x\|^2=(T^{1/2}x,T^{1/2}x)=(Tx,x).
$$
Therefore $\mathcal{N}(T)\subseteq\mathcal{N}(T^{1/2})$. So,
$$
      \overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}=\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(T^{1/2})^{\perp}
$$
Every eigenvector $v$ with non-zero eigenvalue $\mu$ is in the range of $\mathcal{R}(T)$ because $v=T(\frac{1}{\mu}v)$. So every such $v$ is orthogonal to $\mathcal{N}(T^{1/2})$.

Comment: I guess that $\mathcal R(T)$ denotes the image $T(V)$ of $T$. But what is $\overline{\mathcal R(T)}$? Is it the closure of $\mathcal R(T)$? If so, how do we see that it's equal to $\ker(T)^\perp$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Yes, it denotes closure. To show $\mathcal{N}(T)^\perp=\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}$, show $\mathcal{R}(T)^\perp=\mathcal{N}(T)$ and then use the fact that $M^{\perp\perp}=\overline{M}$ for a subspace. To show $\mathcal{R}(T)^\perp=\mathcal{N}(T)$:  $(Tx,y)=0$ for all $x$ iff $(x,Ty)=0$ for all $x$ iff $Ty=0$.